# Problemas tentado alterar a função next()

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, iterator

Preciso fazer essa atividade relacionada a classes, ainda não conheço muito sobre o tema e estou um pouco confuso.

> Escreva uma classe Python com um iterador personalizado, quando a função next() é chamada, ela deve retorna o próximo número primo (começando em 1).

```
class NextPrime:
    def __iter__(self):
        return 1

    def __next__(self, num):
        while True:
            num += 1
            while True:
                print(num)
                for i in range(2, num):
                    if num % i == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    break
            break
        return num


n = NextPrime
print(next(n))
print(next(n))
```

Resultado:

```
line 20, in <module>
    print(next(n))
TypeError: 'type' object is not an iterator
```

Comment: você definiu `next` como sendo um método e está tentando usar como uma função?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O primeiro erro é aqui:

```
n = NextPrime
```

Você está dizendo que `n` vai receber a própria classe `NextPrime`, e não uma instância dela. Para instanciar a classe você deve usar parênteses:

```
n = NextPrime()
```

Mas só isso não é suficiente. [A documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) descreve como criar um iterador, mas de forma resumida, há dois métodos que devem ser implementados da seguinte maneira:

- `__iter__`: retorna o próprio objeto iterador. Ou seja, ele deve retornar `self`, e não `1` como você fez
- `__next__`: retorna o próximo valor (ou lança uma exceção [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) caso não haja mais valores para retornar)

Ambos os métodos não recebem nenhum parâmetro (somente o `self`, claro).

Outro detalhe é que quando o número for 4, seu código entra em *loop* infinito ([veja](https://ideone.com/toX9yc)). Então vamos mudar esse algoritmo.

O `for` não precisa ir até o número, [pode ir até a raiz quadrada dele](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811176). E com exceção do 2 e 3, [todos os outros números primos são da forma `6k - 1` ou `6k + 1`](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html) (ou seja, são antecessores ou sucessores de um múltiplo de 6), então eu posso fazer um loop que só testa esses casos. Vale lembrar também que o 2 é o único número par que é primo, todos os outros primos são ímpares, então a partir do 3 eu posso somar 2 ao número atual (testar os pares é perda de tempo).

Então ficaria assim:

```
from math import sqrt

class NextPrime:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 1 # todos começam em 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self # retorna o próprio objeto, não o valor

    def __next__(self):
        if self.num in (1, 2): # se for 1 ou 2, o próximo número (2 ou 3) com certeza é primo
            self.num += 1
            return self.num

        # aqui eu já sei que "num" é pelo menos 3
        while True:
            self.num += 2 # somo 2, pois não preciso testar números pares
            if self.num % 3 != 0: # se for divisível 3, nem testa o número
                # não é múltiplo de 3, testar se é divisor de 6k - 1 ou 6k + 1
                for i in range(5, int(sqrt(self.num)) + 1, 6):
                    if self.num % i == 0 or self.num % (i + 2) == 0:
                        break # não é primo, testa o próximo
                else: # é primo, interrompe o while
                    break
        return self.num

n = NextPrime()
# imprime os 100 primeiros números primos
for _ in range(100):
    print(next(n))
```

Lembrando que este iterador é infinito, pois não definimos uma condição de parada (poderia ter um limite máximo, e lançar o `StopIteration` caso `self.num` ultrapasse este limite, por exemplo). Ou seja, **não** faça `for i in n`, senão [entrará em *loop* infinito](https://ideone.com/TOGFgA).

Outro detalhe é que o primeiro primo retornado é o 2, já que [o número 1 não é primo](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/one.html).

---

Outra forma de fazer seria criar um [*generator*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr):

```
from math import sqrt

def next_prime(start = 1):
    num = start
    if num == 1:
        num += 1
        yield num
    if num == 2:
        num += 1
        yield num

    while True:
        num += 2 # somo 2, pois não preciso testar números pares
        if num % 3 != 0: # se for divisível 3, nem testa o número
            # não é múltiplo de 3, testar se é divisor de 6k - 1 ou 6k + 1
            for i in range(5, int(sqrt(num)) + 1, 6):
                if num % i == 0 or num % (i + 2) == 0:
                    break # não é primo, testa o próximo
            else: # é primo, retorna
                yield num

n = next_prime()
# imprime os 100 primeiros números primos
for _ in range(100):
    print(next(n))
```