# Numeros primos com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemática

Tentando mil maneiras pra chegar nesse resultado.
Sempre retorna a mesma coisa.

```
number = int(input('Numero: '))

if number >= 1:
    for i in range(1, number):
        if number % i != 0:
            print(number, 'é primo')
        else:
            print(number, 'não é primo')
            break
elif number == 0:
    print(number, 'é zero')
else:
    print(number, 'é negativo')
```

Ex1 : 
Numero: 6 
6 não é primo

Ex2 : 
Numero: 11 
11 não é primo

Comment: Dá um olhada em [Como gerar 200.000 primos o mais rápido possível em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231555/137387) e [Pesquisa contendo primos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5dprimos)

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a resposta!! 
E ainda adicionei uns extras.

```
# numeros primos
if number > 1:
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            print(number, 'não é primo')
            break
    else:
        print(number, 'é primo')
elif number == 0:
    print(number, 'é zero')
elif number == 1:
    print(number, 'é um')
else:
    print(number, 'é negativo')
```

Comment: Exatamente. Acho q se trocar ">=" por ">" ja resolve.
Valeu!!

Answer (score 1):

Complementando as outras respostas, vale comentar também que metade das iterações do

```
for i in range(1, number):
```

são inúteis. Repare que nenhum número é divisível por um que seja maior que sua metade.
Para entender melhor vamos observar algumas coisas:

> Qualquer número dividido pela sua metade resulta em `2`.

Isso é fato: `10/5 = 2`, `20/10 = 2`, `14/7 = 2` etc. Isso implica que qualquer número dividido por um outro que seja maior que sua metade resulta em um valor menor que `2`. `10/6 = 1.6`, `20/11 = 1.81` etc

> O único jeito de uma divisão resultar em `1` é dividindo um número por
> ele mesmo

Com essas duas verdades absolutas, nós podemos passar para a linguagem matemática que, para um número qualquer `x`:

```
>>> x/x = 1 #Um número dividido por ele mesmo resulta em 1

>>> x/(x/2) = 2 #Um número dividido pela sua metade resulta 2
```

e afirmar com certeza que `x` divido por qualquer número `y` tal que `x/2 < y < x` resulta em algum valor `z` tal que `1 < z < 2`. E nenhum deles será inteiro. Ou seja, Sabemos que, por definição, para esses valores, `number % i != 0` sempre retornará `True`, sendo, portanto, um desperdício de recursos testá-los.
é interessante, então, que o seu `for` seja alterado para:

```
for i in range(1, int(number/2)+1):
```

O que deve funcionar tanto para números pares quanto ímpares. Aliás, vale lembrar que nenhum número par é primo (exceto pelo `2`)

Comment: Melhor que isso, você pode fazer os testes de divisão até a √x, não precisa ir até x/2.

Comment: Pois é, tem uma explicação bem detalhada disso. Se não me engano do hkotsubo, em algum post aqui do site, mas não tô conseguindo encontrar pra linkar por aqui.

Comment: @yoyo Tem [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/485989/112052) (e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482985/112052) também, só que não é em Python - mas a ideia é a mesma) - inclusive tem outras melhorias sugeridas (como por exemplo não testar os pares, etc)

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu me referia a [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192690/calcular-os-divisores-de-um-n%c3%bamero-em-python-de-forma-perform%c3%a1tica/486325#486325) Que apesar de não ser especificamente sobre números primos, tem tudo a ver. Vale a leitura

Comment: Mesmo o input já sendo um número inteiro?

Comment: Se você se refere ao `int(number/2)`. Sim, pois o resultado da divisão de um número ímpar por `2` vai resultar em um `float`, mas precisamos de um número inteiro para usar dentro da função `range()`. o `int(number/2)` vai pegar a parte inteira das divisões que resultam em `float`

Answer (score 0):

Um numero é primo quando ele é divisivel por 1 e por ele mesmo.

A variavel `ePrimo` deve contar a quantidade de divisores de `number`, se essa quantidade for exatamente igual a 2 entao `number % i == 0` só foi verdade em duas condicoes, quando `i` igual a 1 ou entao `i` igual ao `number`. Então apenas nesta situação o numero será primo.

```
number = int(input('Numero: '))
ePrimo = 0

for i in range(1, (number + 1)):        
  if number % i == 0:
    ePrimo += 1
    
if ePrimo  == 2 :
  print('primo')
else:
  print('nao primo')
```

Comment: Bem isso.
Tinha passado batido.  
Valeu!!!

Answer (score -1):

Uma linha (uma lista) para números primos menores que 50...

```py
[len(x) for x in list(map(lambda x: [operator.mod(len(range(1,x)), z) for z in range(1,x)], [item for item in range(1,50)])) if x.count(0) == 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

```python
def primo(n):
    resultado = False
    if n==1: resultado
    elif (n==2 or n==3): resultado=True
    else:
        for i in range(2, n-1):
            if n%i==0:
                resultado= False
                break
            else: resultado= True
    return resultado

print(primo(2))
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```python
def is_prime(num):
    if num < 2:  # números menores que 2 não são primos
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(num ** 0.5) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score -3):

Uma das maneiras mais fáceis de solucionar isso que vi é da seguinte forma:

```
primo(numero):
contador = 0
for num in range(1, numero + 1):
    if numero % num == 0:
        contador += 1
if contador == 2:
        print(f'{numero} é primo')
else:
    print(f'{numero} não é primo')
```

Com função:

```
# funcao para ver se o numero é primo

def primo(numero):
    contador = 0
    for num in range(1, numero + 1):
        if numero % num == 0:
            contador += 1
    if contador == 2:
        return True  # se for primo retorna verdadeiro
    else:
        return False  # se nao for primo retorna falso
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).